# How to set height fixed in inputTextarea (PrimeFaces)

Tags: css, primefaces

I try that:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="lineTest" rows="7" cols="33" style="height: 100px; overflow:auto;" value="#{manageLineBean.lineTest}" />
```

But when writing a lot in, this height of the field gets increased. How can I fix this using just `overflow:auto`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to set autoResize="false", otherwise, search similar attribute in docs.

UPD:
http://www.scribd.com/doc/98840317/74/InputTextarea

Comment: Another way is using in css: "resize: none"

Comment: I think that editing CSS in this case -- it's a wrong way :) Because, developer expect to see this setting in xhtml, as attribute of component. And, nobody guarantees that it will be compatible with PrimeFaces.

Comment: You'll need css if you don't want users to resize it manually

Comment: Is there a way to limit the height growing when the autoResize = true?
Eg maxHeight in row 10 the current is 3 the user typed 4 rows increased the size, but typed 11 stop the height growing and scroll bar is appear.

Answer (score 1):

The autoResize=false only removes the resize widget on the right side, but when you enter text it will still grow the input box

This will fix it...

```
textarea.p-inputtext {
  max-height: 5rem;
  resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting `min-height` property helped me:

```
<textarea pInputTextarea [rows]="1" [cols]="30" autoResize="autoResize" style="min-height: 30px; overflow:auto;"></textarea>
```

Comment: The topic is about PrimeFaces, not PrimeNG.